# Trying to make Bootstrap 4 Nav-bar collapse work in Vue

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-4, navbar

I am trying to make bootstrap nav-bar collapsing work on a mobile device because it doesn't work at all. Please don't offer other dependencies like vue-bootstrap or implementing jquery in the code. I am trying to reach the result by this way:

```
<template>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light"  v-bind:class=" { 'navbarOpen': show }">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent"
   aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"
   v-on:click="toggleNavbar">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent"
  v-bind:class="{ in: show }"
 >
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'Header',
  props: {
    msg: String,

  },
  methods: {
    toggleNavbar() {
      this.navbarOpen = !this.navbarOpen;
    }
  },
  computed: {

}
</script>
```

I've added

```
toggleNavbar() {
          this.navbarOpen = !this.navbarOpen;
        }
```

this function but I assume above bindings in HTML are the reasons that it's not working. How can it be fixed and also where should I add navbarOpen = false; for the default mode?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't see that the `show` variable is defined anywhere. Toggle the value of `show`, or instead reference a data variable named `navbarOpen`...

```
  props: {
    msg: String
  },
  data() {
    return {
      show: true
    }
  },
  methods: {
    toggleNavbar() {
      this.show = !this.show;
    }
  }
```

Demo: https://www.codeply.com/go/9jCB86eXFl

Comment: This is quite broken in my browser, menu starts out open and requires 2 clicks to close it initially

Comment: Yes it's because it's out of sync with the Bootstrap Collapse behavior. You can remove the data-toggle="collapse" to prevent this, but then you lose the animation. Anyway, its beyond the scope of the original question.

Comment: You would have to do something like https://codeply.com/p/TUXZlGFSRV to recreate the Bootstrap collapse animation